# Reduce the physical dimensions of a pdf using the command line

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf

I have a scanned pdf of a book which is 366.96 x 624.6 pts according to pdfinfo. Taking 72 pts to the inch this makes the physical dimensions of the pdf about 5.1'' x 8.67''.

I printed it using Lulu.com, which has a template for a 6'' x 9'' book, but their margins screwed up the text and made it unreadable. Is there a way to shrink the pdf to arbitrary physical dimensions using the command line?

Comment: do any of the online sites offer you help? https://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf

Comment: @pdc that site does a great job at compressing the *digital file size*, but I am concerned about the *physical dimensions of the printout*

Answer (score 0):

The question turned out to be answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/676013/scaling-pdf-content-and-page-dimensions-from-command-line?newreg=3d74d740f27c4aaeb1de844eea4bc86a). [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) is a tool which can achieve the correct scaling via the command line, according to pdfinfo.